# package.config dependencies hell

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version

I have to work on a legacy code base that uses packages.config to maintain NuGet dependencies. I implemented a feature that auto rotates a passwords for a service account. I need to install a NuGet package for it to function, 'companyName.PrivilegedAccessManagement'. The problem is whenever I try to add this package, I receive the error message:

> One or more unresolved package dependency constraint detected in  the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraint must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following errors may be blocking the current package operation:
>
> MongoDB.Driver.Core2.13.2 constraint: System.ValueTuple(>=4.5.0), .CommonSecurity.Authentication3.70.30705 constraint Schwab.Logging 3.10.0

How to get this new package installed in the project? I can't migrate the project to `ProjectReference` format. The senior engineers/ organisation is not agreeing with that.

Edit: I've tried adding the packages through NuGet package manager console, adding the package name in packages.config file and csproj file. None of these things seem to have any affect. I also tried to added the dependencies before installing the actual package, it still doesn't work, just the error message changes.

The contents of the pakages.config file are listed below

```
<package id=AutoMapper version=4.2.1 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=CommonLogging version=2.1.2 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Crc32C.NET version=1.0.5.0 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=DnsClient version=1.4.0 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version=5.2.7 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core version=5.2.7 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=MongoDB.Bson version=2.13.2 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=MongoDB.Driver version=2.13.2 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=MongoDB.Driver.Core version=2.13.2 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=MongoDB.Libmongocrypt version=1.2.2 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Newtonsoft.Json version=9.0.1 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=CommonSecurity.Authentication version=3.70.30705 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Logging version=3.10.2 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=One.Crypto version=1.0.10 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Practices.Clients.Core version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Practices.Clients.Enterprise version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Practices.Clients.Rest version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net462>
<package id=Practices.Core version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Practices.Logging.Core version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Practices.Logging.Enterprise version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Practices.Logging.Event version=2.2.4 targetFramework=net451>
<package id=Wcfim version=3.2.16129 targetFramework=net451>
```

Comment: *"The senior engineers/ organisation is not agreeing with that."* - do they have alternatives? they are **seniors** after all. that being said, you should double check the `packages.config` actually contains **all** transitive packages your project require, packages having **compatible** target framework, etc. we can't exactly tell what you should do given its hardly [mcve] and you deliberately hide the package name.

Comment: The package.config doesn't have the package name or the transitive dependency added. I'm trying to add it through the NuGet package manager console and getting the above error. They don't have any alternatives. They suggested some things that didn't work.

Comment: Which framework version are you using? Since everybody is moving to packagereferences these days, packages.config is mostly unsupported and known to have _many_ problems (the fact that you need to manually specify transitive dependencies is just one of them).

Comment: @PMF I'm using .NET framework 4.6.2 in the project. I'm not sure why, but company is reluctant to change project to package reference.

Comment: @ArpitChinmay i am sorry if i'm not verbose enough. what i meant with "package name" is refering to the `id` part in the `<package>` on `packages.config`. list them, check them online what they need (or dig their nuspec).

Comment: Find out why. I guess it's just because "we don't want to put effort into a legacy project" or something similar. But since apparently the project needs to be maintained (that's what you're doing), required upgrades should be made. They cost less than trying to work around old bugs.

Comment: Many packages mentioned here do not seem to exist in public nuget server (Practices.*, Logging, One.Crypto, Wcfim, CommonSecurity.Authentication, CommonLogging) anyway, it's not a package.config vs package reference format, it's a matter of "upgrading" your dependencies, and it's not just "upgrading" but really spend some time on this. There's no magic bullet and we can't really help w/o a reproducing project (which you probably cannot provide).